# Python Pickle throwing FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, pickle

I have a situation in python where, in a python runnable object that is running together with other processes, the following situation happens: If the code is simply:

```
f = open(filename, "rb")
f.close()
```

There is no error, but then when the code changes to the following, introducing pickle in the middle, it throws a `FileNotFoundError`:

```
f = open(filename, "rb")
object = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

I don't understand why, if the file exists, pickle would throw such error.  The complete trace of the error is:

```
task = pickle.load(f)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 852, in RebuildProxy
   return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 706, in __init__
   self._incref()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 756, in _incref
   conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 495, in Client
   c = SocketClient(address)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 624, in SocketClient
   s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: The full error message is: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

Comment: This is obviously not a reproducible/verifiable error with only the information you've given. It's not even debuggable beyond saying "That shouldn't happen; either you're misinterpreting what's happened or there's something weird with your pickle or your stdlib", which doesn't help you very much. Please see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance on what to include in a question.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas: No, please post the full traceback, not just the error string. Also, please edit it into the question instead of posting it in a comment.

Comment: I have posted the traceback together with more context on the setting where it occurs.

Comment: what is the content of filename? Are you sure it exists?

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing libraries that are required by the `load` method of pickle?

Comment: Yes, the file name exists. The content of the filename is a list of objects of a user-defined class.

Comment: Looks like it's to do with the content of the pickle, not the file containing the pickle. Maybe http://jodal.no/post/3669476502/pickling-multiprocessing-connection-objects/ - you can pickle a Multiprocessing connection, but can't unpickle it. Or at least, unpickling is triggering a socket connection to an unavailable endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, that is the issue. The object that I am unpickling contains a queue and a pipe too.

Comment: Came here with a similar problem: If you are multiprocessing, and subprocesses are writing to a managed list of managed dict, if you pickle that list/dict as-is, it will lead to this same `FileNotFound` error when trying to read it back in.  The trick is to simply convert it to a basic list or dict before pickling.

Answer (score 2):

While I'd say that **@TesselatingHeckler** provided the answer, this comment doesn't really fit in the comments section… so it's an extension of that answer.

You can't pickle `multiprocessing` `Queue` and `Pipe` objects, and indeed, some pickled objects only fail on `load`.

I have built a fork of `multiprocessing` that allows most objects to be pickled.  Primarily what was done was to replace `pickle` with a much more robust serializer (`dill`).  The fork is available as part of the `pathos` package (on github).  I've tried to serialize `Pipes` before, and it works, and it also works on a python `socket` and a python `Queue`.  However, it still doesn't work apparently on a `multiprocessing` `Queue`.

```
>>> from processing import Pipe
>>> p = Pipe()
>>> 
>>> import dill
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(p))
(Connection(handle=12), Connection(handle=14))
>>>
>>> from socket import socket
>>> s = socket()
>>> from Queue import Queue as que
>>> w = que()
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(s))
<socket._socketobject object at 0x10dae18a0>
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(w))
<Queue.Queue instance at 0x10db49f38>
>>>
>>> from processing import Queue
>>> q = Queue()
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(q))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.2.dev-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 180, in dumps
    dump(obj, file, protocol, byref, file_mode, safeio)
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.2.dev-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.py", line 173, in dump
    pik.dump(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/processing/queue.py", line 62, in __getstate__
    assertSpawning(self)
  File "/Users/mmckerns/lib/python2.7/site-packages/processing/forking.py", line 24, in assertSpawning
    'processes through inheritance' % type(self).__name__)
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

It seems that the `__getstate__` method for a `multiprocessing` `Queue` is hardwired to throw an error.  If you had this buried inside a class, it might not be triggered until the class instance is being reconstituted from the pickle.

Trying to pickle a `multiprocessing` `Queue` with `pickle` should also give you the above error.